# Change Website Homepage from WordPress to Xenforo

Tags: redirect, homepage, forum

I have a website which has both WordPress and Xenforo forum and both has individual home pages. The Xenforo is installed inside /community directory and WordPress in default directory. Now the website's home page is WordPress, but I want to change it to Xenforo's home page. I tried redirecting, but it is a bit slow. Is there any other way to do it without redirecting?

I redirected from the WordPress homepage to Xenforo, but it was slow and I even tried to run the Xenforo app from the WordPress directory, it did not work properly (duh!!!). I want a way to change the home page without redirecting.

Comment: You probably want to either redirect in your web server configuration or set up a rewrite rule so that the home page URL is served by Xenforo even though it’s usually in the separate directory. This might require some Xenforo configuration too to understand what it needs to do for that URL but I don’t know Xenforo.